# Can YUI2 DataTable utilize YUI3 DataSource?

Tags: javascript, yui

I am currently learning to use the YUI2 DataTable. (I will learn the YUI3 DataTable when it supports inline cell editing).

My question is simple - can I use it with the YUI3 DataSource or must I use YUI2 DataSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to provide a YUI2 DataSource when you create a DataTable instance if only to keep it happy.  It might be a local datasource pointing to an empty array, but the YUI2 DataSource must be there. Later on, you may use any means you want to actually fetch the data and, once you have it, call [onDataReturnInitializeTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.DataTable.html#method_onDataReturnInitializeTable) which is what YUI2 does.  You cannot provide a YUI3 DataSource in the constructor, they have different interfaces, DataTable would not know what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module in the Gallery that wraps a YUI3 Data source with a compatibility layer to be used with YUI2 modules, in particular the DataTable. More information here:

http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/datasource-wrapper

I've used it in code that can be viewed here:

https://github.com/brianjmiller/interchange_mvc/blob/master/share/ic/js/renderer/v2_data_table.js

Answer (score 0):

YUI 3 has began to implement inline-cell editing: http://blunderalong.com/yui/dta/editing/dt_cellediting.html
Which will be put into the YUI-3 library in a couple weeks:

http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/datatable-celleditor-inline

Basically, hold tight for ~ 2 weeks and it will be done!
I too have been using YUI 2 datatables since version 2.4 and have not yet moved to YUI 3 yet!

Comment: I think you got it wrong. The given blog is a blog of Todd Smith who implements the inline cell editing in his free time. He is not part of the YUI3 team, which neglected the inline editing functionality for several years now. Only recently a YUI3 team member (Anthony Pipkin) was assigned to deal with it and I can bet it would take him more than 2 weeks to do it. As for the Todd's implementation - he does what is best for his needs, sharing the results with the community, which is great. But my particular needs are different and so I implemented my own scheme.

Comment: If you are willing to post what you have done, i'm sure it would be helpful to the community. If it is not sensitive info, maybe you could blog about it.

Comment: I spoke with t_smith directly on the #yui freenode channel and he told me that it would be in the CDN in about 2 weeks, btw.

Comment: I am still in the process of working on it. Basically, I needed a different user experience. It is sumarized (quite briefly) here - http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=92&t=10683&start=21